# Remote action in Unity3D using VIVE controller (VR)

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive

Anyone knows how to post a controller trigger-press from a VIVE controller in one PC to another PC using Unity remote action or something else?

The multiplayer game is fine and users can see each other but I need to send the action from one controller to another user's controller like if User#1 presses the trigger, it acts like the second user's controller is being pressed as well. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RPC method and manage the event of local player & server player. This depends on the multiplayer services you are using.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use this but have some issues with

Comment: Can you share something Like which Service you used and how you have tried?